# Any FTP server library package for iPhone/iPad?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

Any FTP server library package for iPhone/iPad ?

Is DiddyFtpServer good ?

http://code.google.com/p/diddyftpserver/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, diddy is probably what you are looking for. Other than that, you will have to write your own ftp server.

Comment: Sorry, I need a FTP server api, not client.

Comment: For Diddy FTP Server, I had mentioned in my original question already.